# Processing Lists and List.Take()

Tags: c#, linq

Given:

```
// got a dictionary wrapped in a class - reading values into list
List<string> caplist = QuizData.Dict.Values.ToList();

// shuffle cap list - I know it's not "really random"
var rnd = new Random();
var shufcapList = caplist.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next());

// take first fifteen from shuffled list for caps choices
var firstFifteenItems = shufcapList.Take(15);
foreach (string cap1 in firstFifteenItems) {
    Console.WriteLine("1st_15"+cap1); //seems OK 

}

// take first 6 from firstFifteenItems (it's been shuffled) list for states
var firstSixItems = firstFifteenItems.Take(6); 
foreach (string cap2 in firstSixItems)   {
    Console.WriteLine("1st_6" + cap2);
}
```

But firstSixItems is **not** a subset of firstFifteenItems. Shouldn't it be? is I count 15 items in firstFifteenItems looking at the console output. I count 6 items from firstSixItems but those items are not in firstFifteenItems. I want to non destructively copy the first 6 items from one list into another. I am missing something obvious? Grateful for help.

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" here is lazy evaluation.

Those enumerables are not evaluated until they are enumerated.  Until then the `IEnumerable` returned by the call to `OrderBy` is simply a set of instructions as to *how* to retrieve the elements, but there aren't actually any results yet.  The call to `Take(15)` isn't actually evaluated until the `foreach` loop.

The call to `Take(6)` is evaluated in its following `foreach`, but it is an enumerable derived from `firstFifteenItems`, which is itself a lazy enumerable of the original `OrderBy`, so it calls `rnd.Next()` *again* a bunch of times.  Of course, `rnd.Next()` returns a (probably) different result each time it is called.

Call `ToList()` on the `OrderBy` and you'll see the behavior you expect as `ToList()` will enumerate and store the result.

Comment: Adding the ToList as recommended fixed it - it gave me the behavior I expected, so it's:   var firstFifteenItems = shufcapList.Take(15).ToList(); and it works. This is definitely something I need to read more about and understand. All the answers were helpful - appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

What you witness is defered execution. What you think are list you generate with `Take` and `OrderBy` are `IEnumerable`s. `IEnumerable`s are not containers like `List<>`. They are nothing but a promise to yield data when enumerated. *When enumerated* is the key here.

```
// this line DOES NOT create a new shuffled list.
// it creates a promise that once called upon, shufcaplist will yield the caplist in random order
var shufcapList = caplist.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next());

// this again is not a list of 15 items. Instead, it's the promise to yield 15 items, taken 
// ffrom the promise described above.
var firstFifteenItems = shufcapList.Take(15);

// this is basically the same as above. But note that the ordering, as it's nothing concrete 
// but only a promise, will be done AGAIN and yield different results.
var firstSixItems = firstFifteenItems.Take(6);
```

What you want is to *materialize* the promises into real containers. You can do this by calling `foreach` yourself and storing the results or by calling an extension that returns an actual container like `ToList` or `ToArray`

Answer (score 0):

Despite the two answers already provided to this question, I'll add another one, to state it in a different way -

To make it very very clear, when you say - `var shufcapList = caplist.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next());` there is **no** list.. probably will be more appropriate to call it a query.
Think of it as an expression, unless you are materializing the query by doing something like `.ToList` or `.ToArray`

When **iterating** over any such query using `foreach`, you end up evaluating the query..

In other words, even if you forget `Take()` for a moment..
iterating over the query twice, will / could give you different results (due to use of random in this case), just like it would, if you execute a query twice against a database (data may have changed between the two executions)